# Fibered surfaces with sections and generic fibers iso to projective space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is an exercise from Liu's book on Algebraic Geometry, exercise 8.3.5c)

Let $f:X \rightarrow S$ be a fibered surface over a Dedekind scheme of dimension $1$, with generic fiber $X_{K(S)} \cong \mathbb{P}^1_{K(S)}$. Let $s \in S$ be such that $X_s$ is geometrically integral.

I am trying to show that there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $s$ such that $f^{-1}(V) \cong \mathbb{P}^1_V$.

In a) one showed that if $S$ is local, then $X_s \cong \mathbb{P}^1_{k(s)}$ .
In b) one showed that if $D$ is the Cartier divisor corresponding to a section of $X \rightarrow S$, then under the assumption that $S$ is local, $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ is very ample.

I believe I can do a proof of $c)$ using very general properties that are not all too illuminating, and I suspect Liu wanted one to use $a$ and $b)$ in conjunction to show $c)$, but I can't seem to get it to work. I suppose one wants to show that there is a non-empty open subset $V$ of $S$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ restricted to $V$ is very ample. Further, a trivial thing to note is to note that we have an isomorphism on the generic point, and we want to extend this somehow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:X\to S$ be as in the question, and consider $E = f_\ast \mathcal \omega_{X/S}^{\vee}$, where $\omega_{X/S}$ is the relative dualizing sheaf of $X\to S$. (What you want is local on $S$, so you can replace $S$ from the start by a dense open such that $f$ is smooth over this open.)

The morphism $f$ factors via $\mathbb P(E)\to S$. Note that $E$ is a vector bundle on $S$ of rank $3$:
$$\mathrm{rk} f_\ast \omega_{X/S}^\vee = h^0(\mathbb P^1_k, \omega_{\mathbb P^1_k}^\vee) = 3.$$ Choose $U = \mathrm{Spec} \ A$ dense open affine in $X$ such that $E|_U$ is trivial and $U$ contains $s$. Then $f:f^{-1}U\to U$ is still as in the question and factors through $\mathbb P(E|_U) = \mathbb P^2_U$.  (I'm not going to write $f|_{f^{-1}U}$.)

Since the degree of $f_\eta :X_\eta \to \mathrm{Spec} \ K(U)$ is two (as it is the $2$-uple embedding of $\mathbb P^1$ in $\mathbb P^2$), we see that $f$ is a relative conic in $\mathbb P^2_S$ with a smooth fibre over $s$. (Explanation: the embedding of $X$ in $\mathbb P^2_A$ is given by a polynomial which has degree two regarded as a polynomial with coefficients in the function field of $A$. So then it has degree two to start with.) Choose $V\subset U$ such that $f$ is smooth over $V$ (unnecessary step now). Then $f$ is a smooth conic in $\mathbb P^2_V$ with a section. Therefore, $f$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1_V$ over $V$. (Explanation:  any Brauer-Severi variety with a section is split.)

Edit: added some more details (and rewrote the answer). Everyone is allowed to add more details of course.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which is very good but seems to be a bit different from what I have been thinking of. I can't see how this uses the hypothesis on $D$ in $b)$ in any way (maybe I'm incorrect?) and further, why must $f$ be a relative conic in $\mathbb{P}^2_S$?

Comment: Dear @user101036, my guess is that this method is also how you show a), invoking the fact that $Pic(B) =0$ if $B$ is a "trait" (ie spectrum of a dvr); you will also need something about conics there. Namely, a geometrically integral conic with a point is isomorphic to the projective line. Moreover, I think $\mathcal O_X(D)$ is the pull-back of $\mathcal O(1)$ to $X$ via $X\to \mathbb P(E)$. The family $X$ is a conic because the embedding is of degree two.

Comment: Ah, my method was a bit different from yours. I used properness of the scheme for the case when a) is local. How do you conclude that the embedding of degree 2?

Comment: Dear @user101036 Is it not sufficient to check this on the generic fibre?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I didn't know this was sufficient, but if you say so I believe. I understand everything perfect up to "we may and do assume that E is trivial", and the only sentence I am having trouble with is "Then f is a relative conic in $\mathbb{P}^2_S$. Why $\mathbb{P}^2_S$? (I am probably missing something obvious). If one can check degree on the generic point, I agree with the rest.

Comment: Dear @user101036 Please see the edited answer. The rank of $E$ is three. That's why you get $\mathbb P^2$. OW I see what I miswrote. I took the wrong vector bundle $E$. Of course, $f_\ast \mathcal O_X = \mathcal O_S$ (because the fibres are connected). See edited answer.